# Localized UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, localization

I'm currently localizing our ios app, which has proven a smooth ride so far except for one thing. How can I set the label texts of the segments in a UISegmentedControl from the code?

Googling has so far not led me to anything, so all help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, Alexander. Just what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title forSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segment`